# svn export (rabbit-svn) deleted local files

Tags: svn, svn-export, rabbitvcs

I executed svn export with rabbit-svn in a folder and it deleted all the folders which were present before . I don't understand this behavior.Can any one help me with that. And also is there any way the deleted folders back ?

Thanks.

Comment: were you able to find any way to recover your data? This happened to me also, used TestDisk to recover but was not able get anything apart from empty folder.

Comment: @Ankit ..no i was not able to recover my files :(